# Moving data to DX register, overflow cannot be evaluated - 8086

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, x86-16

I was asked a question "Write assembly code that moves the word sized data in the addresses 4AB08h and 4AB09h to DX"

And I wrote this code

```
.model small
.stack 32h
.data

.code
main: 
mov dl, [4AB08h] 
mov dh, [4AB09h]
end main
```

It's not working. The error im getting is "overflow! - cannot be evaluated mov dl, [4AB08h] "

Where am I going wrong and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use 16 bit offsets. You will need to set a segment register to an appropriate base address and use an adjusted offset that fits into 16 bits.

PS: you don't need to load `dl` and `dh` separately.

Comment: I tried fixing it by writing mov dl, [4AB0h][0008h]  instead. but now i reach the address 4AB8 instead of 4AB08

Comment: You need to do what I told you. Load a segment register.